# Display JSON info on php view page

Tags: php, json

I have an url that returns the following json code if I type that url on a Mozilla tab:

```
{
    "results":[
        {
            "hostname":"localhost",
            "target":{
                "value":"localhost",
                "type":"ADDRESS"
            },
            "nmap-command":"/usr/bin/nmap -T5 -oX - localhost",
            "nmap-version":"7.01",
            "device-type":"unknown",
            "running-os":"unknown",
            "os-details":"unknown",
            "open-ports":[
                {
                    "service":"http",
                    "version":"unknown",
                    "port-number":"80"
                },
                {
                    "service":"mysql",
                    "version":"unknown",
                    "port-number":"3306"
                },
                {
                    "service":"unknown",
                    "version":"unknown",
                    "port-number":"55555"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "targets":[
        {
            "value":"localhost",
            "type":"ADDRESS"
        }
    ],
    "start":1498303529660,
    "finish":null,
    "policy":{
        "description":"Análisis completo",
        "version":"1.0",
        "metadata":{
            "description":"Análisis completo",
            "version":"1.0",
            "name":"completo"
        },
        "params":[
            "-O",
            "-sV",
            "-T5"
        ],
        "name":"completo"
    },
    "status":"FINISHED",
    "id":"ebac2c53-2595-4523-bcaa-d2d49cb310d8"
}
```

On the other hand I have this on my view.php page, note that the url applied to file_get_contents() is the same url that I've used on the Mozzilla tab:

```
$json = file_get_contents(http://localhost:55555/rema/analyzers/NMAP/analyses/a7819f0d-9c3e-4a74-b4bc-1f10bebd96c7);

$parsed_json = json_decode($json,true);

print_r($parsed_json);
```

The print_r output is the following:

```
Array (
    [finish] => 
    [start] => 1498311204774
    [targets] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [value] => localhost
            [type] => ADDRESS
        )
    )
    [policy] => Array (
        [description] => Análisis completo
        [version] => 1.0
        [metadata] => Array (
            [description] => Análisis completo
            [version] => 1.0
            [name] => completo
        )
        [params] => Array (
            [0] => -O
            [1] => -sV
            [2] => -T5
        )
        [name] => completo
    )
    [status] => STARTED
    [id] => aabd7375-f9e8-41db-815c-9a6dd5941ef6
)
```

Some information seems to be missed and I really dont know why, I dont get the hostname, the target and all the information related to nmap like nmap-version, device-type, runnig-os etc... and the same with open-ports info. Please help and thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
**that's what I get on the browser url , maybe it could help**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssEKG.png)

Comment: Probably because the headers are missing from the request in `file_get_contents()`. Try using cURL instead.

Comment: @BenM "the headers" doesn't tell the OP very much. Which headers do you suggest sending that would cause the endpoint to output the same data as the browser request is outputting?

Comment: `json_decode` will not drop those values, so the only way they'd be missing is if the endpoint didn't include them in its response. I suggest running `var_dump` on the `file_get_contents` call, and if it truly didn't send all the data then you'll need to analyze what's different about the browser request and your PHP request. For example, have you authenticated with the service in your browser?

Comment: Hi, and thanks for answering so fast, I made what you said and did a var_dump on file get_contents and the same values still missed, so I'll check the php and the browser request and see if something its wrong

Comment: just a guess here, but `status=STARTED` in your `file_get_contents` call might suggest that the request isn't properly handled. in your initial example, `"status":"FINISHED"`. As Ben suggested, try curl with `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`

Comment: Tried this -> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); but still don't working